# c++ operator<< member of class

Tags: c++, operators

I have a problem with the << operator in C++. I need this operation work:

```
  cout << comp2 << comp1;


class Compo
{
    string name;
    int power;
    string app;

public:
    Compo(string s, string a, int p):name(s), power(p),app(a){};
    //~Compo();    

     string GetAsString()const{
        ostringstream oss;    
        oss << name << " [ " << power << " ] desc: " << app << endl;        
        return oss.str();
    };


     string &operator<<(Compo& aux)const{               
        return aux.GetAsString();
    };
};

void main()
{
    Compo comp1("Pencil","Best",12);
    Compo comp2("Notes","Not Best",22);
    cout << comp2 << comp1;        
    cin.get();
}
```

i have erro on `cout << comp2`

the error description is,

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'Compo' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

and one warn alert,

> returning address of local variable or temporary

ho i need change to this works.

Comment: You need to implement it as a free function.  The link I provided when I voted to close this question tells you why,.

Comment: @JohnKugelman:  Maybe there is.  I invite you to find a better one.

Comment: << and >> operators are implemented like two scrolls down in the provided link

Comment: Is not possible using the friend function.

Comment: Make `put()` public then (see my answer) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this operator:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const Compo& c)
{
   return o << c.GetAsString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare a standalone output operator method to do this (class free function).

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Compo& obj)
{
    obj.put(os);
    return os;
}
```

In class `Compo` have:

```
// ...
public:
    void put(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        // output member values here ...
    }
// ...
```

**UPDATE:**
Or alternatively (if you can't change `Comp` actually):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Compo& obj)
{
    os << obj.GetAsString();
    return os;
}
```

IMHO the 1st solution I've proposed here is the more flexible one, for fulfilling future requirements in the end. It might be used with implementations for `std::ostream` that don't handle stringyfied formats.

Comment: Put is the my GetAsString method!

Comment: @Góis _'Put is the my GetAsString method!'_ Not really (have a closer look to the method signatures!!), but you might use it to implement `put()` or the `operator<<()` methods.

Comment: @Góis I've put some updates to clarify ...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't find any operator<< which takes as a left argument `std::ostream` and as right argument `Compo`. You defined one which takes as a left argument a `std::string` and as the right argument `Compo`.
Try:

```
class Compo{
//Stuff
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Compo& aux);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Compo& aux)
{
    o << name << " [ " << power << " ] desc: " << app << endl;
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Compo
{
    string name;
    int power;
    string app;

public:
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Compo&);
     ....
     .....

};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Compo& c)
{
   out << c.name << "[" << c.power << " ] desc: " << c.app << endl;
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** The OP already stated, that it's not possible for him/her to use `friend` ...